# Ionic 2 showing old state in browser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2, I started a blank application which has hello world text, I have changed the `home.html` as well as the `home.ts`.

But still when I do `ionic serve`, it still shows me the initial state which has hello world label.
Is there some form of caching, or am I missing some clean and build step?

Needless to say that I am new to Ionic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ionic serve` rebuilds every time you save. If your app hasn't changed, you either haven't saved the changes, or the build failed. Search the messages coming from `ionic serve` for syntax errors, etc

Comment: ok, so you mean that in case of failed build, it runs the last successful build?

Comment: In short, yes it does